# How to change dynamically jQuery dataTable pagenumber in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have this code which is fetching data from service according to button click. What I want this when I click previous or next button, I want to change pagenumber on bottom of dataTable.

```js
$('.paginate_button.previous', this.api().table().container())
                            .on('click', function(){
                               // alert("Doruk");
                                if(pageNumber > 1) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "http://192.168.1.171:8080/LogWS/rest/v1/logs/normalized-logs-paged?pageNumber=" + pageNumber-- + "&&pageCount=10",
                                        type: "post",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        traditional: true,
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        processData: false,
                                        headers: {
                                            Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("globalAuthenticationKey")
                                        },
                                        data:
                                            JSON.stringify(hostAddresses)

                                        ,

                                        success: function (response) {

                                            var Table = document.getElementById("applicationviewTableID");
                                            Table.innerHTML = "";
                                            for (var i = 0; i < response.logData.length; i++) {
                                                var trHTML = '';
                                                // var trHTML2 = '';
                                                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + response.logData[i].ip + '</td><td>' + response.logData[i].application + '</td><td>' + "" + '</td>';
                                                $('#applicationviewTableID').append(trHTML);
                                                /*  trHTML2 += '<tr><td>' + response.logData[i].ip + '</td><td>' + response.logData[i].application + '</td><td>' + response.logData[i].operation + '</td><td>' + response.logData[i].entityType + '</td><td>' + response.logData[i].entity + '</td><td>' + response.logData[i].time + '</td>'
                                                  $('#DetailedApplicationsMalwareTableBodyID').append(trHTML2);*/
                                            }



                                            console.log( $('.paginate_button.active')[0]);


                                        },
```

Below code shows me  html code piece that I want to change in console.

```js
console.log( $('.paginate_button.active')[0]);
```

It shows

```html
<li class="paginate_button active"><a href="#" aria-controls="ApplicationVİEWTABLE" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
```

And I want to change that "1" inside "a" tag

How can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the inner a-tag too. 
Then you can get the text like this:

```
$('.paginate_button.active a').text();
```

or edit like this:

```
$('.paginate_button.active a').text("2")
```